# How to check Billing Agreement is active or cancel?

Tags: php, paypal

I am using Reference Transaction API in PayPal and not sure whether Billing Agreement is active or not while billing. I would like to know in advance if Billing Agreement is cancelled.

I am wondering to have callback call on Billing agreement cancel call.

Answer (score 3):

to check the status of a Billing Agreement you can use the BAUpdate API (NVP: METHOD=BillAgreementUpdate).

Normally this API is used to delete a Billing Agreement, but if you use it without the BillingAgreementStatus field, it returns the current status of Billing Agreement, allowing you to know if a Billing Agreement is still valid or not.

In fact if a Billing Agreement is no longer valid, Paypal will respond with an errorcode 10201 "Billing Agreement was cancelled"

source [API Operations for Reference Transactions](https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECReferenceTxns), Angell EYE PayPal NVP CodeIgniter Library (PHP)

Regards