# Braintree BillingAgreement ID Lookup in PayPal REST API

Tags: java, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree

I've created a Java App which uses the Braintree SDK for the checkout process with PayPal.

I've created a sandbox account at PayPal together with one merchant Sandbox account. Next I have created a Braintree AccessToken using the merchant just created. After creating the Braintree Access Token in PayPal I have noticed that an REST APP for the merchant account was created automatically. In the automatically created `REST APP` I have activated all possible options. Further I have stored the ClientID and the ClientSecret to generate an AccessToken using the PayPal REST API.

During the first payment, a Braintree Customer is created for the user and a
a billing agreement is created for the user. All further payments are now charged without entering the PayPal credentials of the user again. That checkout flow works without any problems so far.

Now I wanted to implement a function to check if the billing agreement is still active because a user may have revoked it meanwhile. Inspecting the `PaymentMethod` instance of type `PayPalAccount` of the corresponding `Customer` instance I see a property called `billingAgreementId` which matches the billing agreement id st of the PayPal transactions of the user and further matches the billing agreement deposited in the PayPal account of the user. The ID starts with "`B-`" and than some numbers.

The problem is I am not able to find a REST API method within PayPal which allows me to use the `billingAgreementId` of the `PaymentMethod` instance to check whether the billing agreement is still valid or not.

I've tried the REST API methods listed here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/
The deprecated one and the new one but neither of both return information about the billing agreement. Instead I get an error returned "Profile ID is not valid" or something like this.

Further the "`B-`" pattern of `billingAgreementId`does not seem to match the pattern of the IDs used in the PayPal API examples.

What I've also noticed: I can not get any information using the PayPal REST API about PayPal transactions / payments / orders generated by Braintree. Is Braintree doing someting different here so that these transactions / payments / orders are not visible using the PayPal REST API? It seems like it is not possible to get any information out of the PayPal REST API regarding transactions / payments / orders created using Braintree.

Is there a way to check whether the `billingAgreementId` in the Braintree `Customer` `PaymentMethod` is still valid or not? Or do I have to check the ResponseCode of an failed `CheckOut` and delete the stored `PaymentMethod` of the `Customer` I've the response code is mapped to the revoked billing agreement status?

I've read about achieving this by using webhooks but on the other side I've also read that the PayPal webhooks are not really reliable.

Answer (score 0):

It has not been documented many places, I think one of the few pages that currently makes some reference to it is https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/upgrade-integration/

But if you piece it together, there is this URL you can try a GET request to with a standard REST http header of:  "Authorization: Bearer {token}"

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing-agreements/agreements/B-XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

YMMV

---

Another solution would be to try the old BAUpdate API: [How to check Billing Agreement is active or cancel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698471/how-to-check-billing-agreement-is-active-or-cancel)

(I am not seriously suggesting this, but it's an old classic NVP/SOAP PayPal API that's probably technically still around if for some strange reason you wanted to try it)